# MSYS2+MinGW64: why do ldd and objdump find different DLL dependencies?

Tags: dll, mingw-w64, msys2, objdump, ldd

I get different DLLs dependencies reported by different tools and like to deeply understand why. So answers like "tool xxx is crap, use cool yyy" are opinions and not welcome. Answers like "you have wrong path order" or "you missed to export XXX=yyyy" are not what I focus for, but if they are applicable, those are welcome too. What I exactly want to understand is for instance, which PE/ELF tables which of the tools use and which they can't see. All under the aspect of mingw / msys2 environment.

For completeness: I compiled my program inside Codelite IDE following exactly this [Setup Instructions for Codelite](https://docs.codelite.org/getting_started/windows/) and inserted /mingw64/bin:/clang64/bin: in front of PATH. The expectation is that this has nothing to do with my observation. Just for the case I couldn't see the wood because of all the trees. Inserted my code into the helloworld example.

For completeness II: the ucrt variant is installed for different projects. I did not use it here.

For completeness III: I give *all* my instructions here. Expecting, 80% have nothing to do with the question, but just in case you see things I missed.

Given: MSYS2 (Sept.2022, msys2-x86_64-20220904.exe) with:

```
pacman -Suy \
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc \
base-devel development \
sys-utils \
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain \
libmodbus \
mingw-w64-x86_64-codelite
```

Opened a MSYS terminal:

```
$ which gcc && which g++ && which clang
/mingw64/bin/gcc
/mingw64/bin/g++
/mingw64/bin/clang
codelite &
```

Inside Codelite I only changed Settings | Build Settings | Compilers to "MinGW 32bit (MSYS2 64bit)" and therein the two cfg lines:

```
make       C:/c/msys64/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=sh.exe
makedir    mkdir -p
```

Program was then built via codelite generated makefile:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/c/msys64/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 SHELL=sh.exe -e -f  Makefile
...[cut]...
C:/c/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -c  protocol_writer.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -o Debug/protocol_writer.cpp.o -I. -I.
C:/c/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe  -c  scan_dtsu666_main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -o Debug/scan_dtsu666_main.cpp.o -I. -I.
C:/c/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -o Debug/modbus-dtu-dump @"modbus-dtu-dump.txt" -L.  -lmodbus
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Program was not starting because of missing DLLs (no pop-up or error msg). Now we come to the core issue. I invoked:

```
$ which ldd
  /usr/bin/ldd
$ ldd modbus-dtu-dump.exe
    ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffdf2c70000)
    ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll (0x77310000)
    wow64.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/wow64.dll (0x7ffdf2510000)
    wow64win.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/wow64win.dll (0x7ffdf1be0000)

$ which objdump
  /mingw64/bin/objdump
$ objdump --private-headers modbus-dtu-dump.exe | grep 'DLL'
    DLL Name: libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
    DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
    DLL Name: libmodbus-5.dll
    DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
    DLL Name: libwinpthread-1.dll
    DLL Name: libstdc++-6.dll
```

... and wonder, why ldd doesn't tell anything about the mingw runtimes, while objdump doesn't tell about the windows os core dependencies.

Edit:
As I wrote in a side note "Program was not starting because of missing DLLs (no pop-up or error msg).", there seems to be another miss-configuration. Once I changed the IDE settings to use the 64bit target, it was able to start and all-aspect debugging. I'll keep this up to date, for the case Google leads some people to here, searching for similar codelite or mingw problems. Goal is to have both architectures compile-able and debug-able.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ldd` is a Cygwin-based program (as everything in `/usr/bin` is), so I'm not surprised that it fails on non-cygwin binaries.

Comment: Oh, good advice! Looks like the MSYS2 ships a ldd for only the Cygwin part, no such tool in the MinGW or UCRT shell variants. At least in default setup. Will look for a compatible replacement now ...

Comment: As documented, ldd is too clever by half and actually executes the program.   Using the debugger interface to spy on loaded DLLs, attempting to stop the program before its entrypoint is reached.  Might have been a good idea 15+ years ago, today you see it loading the wow64 emulator that's used to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: The replacement is called `ntldd`. I.e. the package for your env is `mingw-w64-x86_64-ntldd`.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for this little insight! Exactly the kind of answers I wished to get.